# cygwin warning: Error opening keyring and long pause

Tags: cygwin, x11, dbus

I'm running cygwin64 on Win10-64bit and have an X11 server running with a dbus-daemon.  The X11 server is run rootless using startxwin.  I'm not running anything gnome or kde based (because of the problem below).

I get long pause (30+ sec) and an error like:

```
(process:1199): GLib-GIO-WARNING **: Problems looking up entry in keyring: Error opening keyring “/cygdrive/c/Users/dc5/.dbus-keyrings/org_freedesktop_general” for reading: Failed to open file “/cygdrive/c/Users/dc5/.dbus-keyrings/org_freedesktop_general”: No such file or directory
```

This happens whenever any modern X11 app tries to start:  emacs-X11, gnome-terminal, etc.

I tried creating a file there, but then it complains that it isn't valid and there is still the long hang.

It isn't clear to me why anything is trying to open a keyring.  Sometimes it triggers at weird times.  I just hit it loading the magit package under emacs-win32.

How can I either create a keyring or make it not try to find one?

Comment: The hang is likely because D-Bus isn’t working, so whatever D-Bus call an application is trying to do is timing out and the application is hanging until the timeout is reached. The `.dbus-keyrings` directory is part of the auth mechanism from D-Bus clients to servers (see https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html#auth-mechanisms-sha), but I don’t know how it’s meant to be set up on Windows. Have you tried just creating the .dbus-keyrings directory, but not the file inside? Does the `dbus-daemon` process output any log messages?

Comment: The directory was there.  I don't know where to look for dbus-daemon logs.

Comment: Run `dbus-daemon` with `DBUS_VERBOSE=1` and its output will be printed in the terminal you run it in.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that.  It get's started 'automagically'.  When I try manually, I get:  ```$ DBUS_VERBOSE=1 dbus-daemon.exe
No configuration file specified.```